# How to type a rest parameter that takes an array of rxjs operators?

Tags: typescript, rxjs

I'm trying to find a way to type a rest parameter that takes an array of rxjs operators, which are essentially observables.

So far this is the implementation i have. Typescript isn't complaining but this isn't typed good enough.

```
testFunction(...args: any[]):BehaviorSubject<any>{
   this.selector.pipe(...args, delay(1000)).subscribe();
}
```

The function should be able to take an infinite number of rxjs operators. Ex:

```
testFunction(take(1), skip(2), ...);
```

How would i be able to express that in typescript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`pipe()`](https://rxjs.dev/api/index/function/pipe) function is expecting `UnaryFunction<any, any>` parameters:

```
testFunction(...args: UnaryFunction<any, any>[]): BehaviorSubject<any>{
   this.selector.pipe.apply(this.selector, ...args, delay(1000)).subscribe();
}
```

You can't really do better than that (typing the `BehaviorSubject` for instance) without overloading several times your own function, depending on the number of parameters, as it's done with `pipe` in RxJS.

Comment: How do you deal with the `A spread argument must either have a tuple type or passed to a rest parameter` error ?